# What's wrong with my bash script to iterate over files

Tags: bash, freebsd

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="release-candidate-1.0.tar.gz"
patch_base="patch-1.0."
patch_extension=".tar.gz"
i="1"

while [ -f $file ]
do
    echo $file
    file="${patch_base}${i}${patch_extension}"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

When running the script I get:

```
# ./script.sh
file=release-candidate-1.0.tar.gz: Command not found.
path_base=patch-1.0.: Command not found.
patch_extension=.tar.gz: Command not found.
i=1: Command not found.
file: Undefined variable.
#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might also want to remove all white-space in assignments. `file = ...` will execute "file" with arguments "= ...".

Comment: Remove those spaces around the `=` sign.

Comment: It was changed from a `bash` script to a `csh` script!!! Why?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Sorry I was just trying it out.

Comment: Guys, please don't down vote me. I am a bash noob, I just need to write this one bash script to apply all the patches because there are hundreds of them. I don't want to apply them manually. Just trying to make my life easier :)

Comment: If your question is about `sh` on *FreeBSD* (not `bash` on *Linux*) please tag it appropriately!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was I had no bash installed on my machine. Silly :D

I installed bash like this:

```
portsnap fetch
portsnap extract update
cd /usr/ports/shells/bash
make install clean
```

And then used this bash script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

file="release-candidate-1.0.tar.gz";
patch_base="patch-1.0.";
patch_extension=".tar.gz";
last_patch=500;
got_all_files=1;

for (( i = 0; i <= $last_patch; i++))
do
    if [ $i -eq 0 ]
    then
        if [ ! -f $file ]
        then
            got_all_files=0;
        fi
    else
        file=$patch_base$i$patch_extension;
        if [ ! -f $file ]
        then
            got_all_files=0;
        fi
    fi
done

if [ $got_all_files -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Missing files.";
    exit;
fi

file="release-candidate-1.0.tar.gz";

for (( i = 0; i <= $last_patch; i++))
do
    if [ $i -eq 0 ]
    then
        tar xzvpf $file
        ./install.sh
        ./services restart
    else
        file=$patch_base$i$patch_extension;
        tar xzvpf $file
        ./patch.sh
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest removing spaces around the equal sign:

```
file="release-candidate-1.0.tar.gz"
patch_base="patch-1.0."
patch_extension=".tar.gz"
i="1"
```

And till your script is satisfactory, you could run it e.g. with

```
/bin/bash -vx script.sh
```

Comment: Did you try to run it with `/bin/bash -vx` ? You should then understand what is happening!

Comment: Try again with `/bin/bash` and please, read some introductory material about commands and shell scripting.

Comment: I have updated my question with new error messages. Please take a look.

Comment: You changed `bash` to `csh`... this is wrong!   http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying it out, if it won't work. It seems I don't have bash installed on my FreeBSD box. I go install it and I will try then.

Comment: Or use `/bin/sh -vx` or just add the `-vx` in your script's first line starting with `#!`

Answer (score 1):

bash requires that variable assignments are not separated from the '=' by spaces. It has to be all run together, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="release-candidate-1.0.tar.gz"
patch_bas="patch-1.0."
patch_extension=".tar.gz"
i="1"

while [ -f $file ]
do
    echo $file
    file="${patch_base}${i}${patch_extension}"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

But, there's more

A more typical way for testing for a range of patchs would be

```
for i in {1..10} ; do
   file="${patch_base}${i}${patch_extension}"
   if [ -f ${file} ] ; then
      echo "Found ${file}"
   else
      echo "NO ${file}"
   fi
done
```

You can change the `{1..10}` to any range you fine useful. OR if some numbers are missing in the range, you can just type the values you want to test for, i.e. `for i in 2 4 6 ; do` .

I hope this helps.

Comment: But I don't know how many patches there are. So I have to use while because there could be 20 patches, but there could also be 120.

Comment: The only thing I know they all follow the same naming convention.

Comment: Ok, while loop makes sense :-). Good luck.